# jQuery: Intercept original DOM ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would it be possible to somehow intercept the DOM ready event so that anything normally triggered within, say, `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` would not be executed? And then later manually trigger the event so that the code *was* executed?

In my case, I have a large amount of existing code that already relies on `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` and my hope is that I would not have to do a search/replace to have all of it rely on a custom manually triggered event.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) is made for such need

> Any event handlers attached with
>   .bind() or one of its shortcut methods
>   are triggered when the corresponding
>   event occurs. They can be fired
>   manually, however, with the .trigger()
>   method. A call to .trigger() executes
>   the handlers in the same order they
>   would be if the event were triggered
>   naturally by the user:

Comment: But how do I prevent the original event from triggering? As far as I can tell e.preventDefault() is not possible in this particular case.

Comment: when u not want to trigger any event on dom Ready then why u write inside `ready`

Comment: I'm basically trying to avoid rewriting a large collection of existing scripts that currently rely on the DOM ready event. My hope was that there would be some way to intercept it and manually trigger it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want something to be "normally" triggered, it should not be in `$(document).ready(on_ready_func)`. Everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded.

Instead, from on_ready_func cherrypick the things you want to trigger manually into another function say manual_func, and call that function at event of your choice.

Note that, `ready` function cannot be triggered using trigger, so you cannot fire the func again, unless you have it as a separate function.

Split-up is your best option.

```
var manual_func = function(){
    // Manual loads
}

var on_ready_func = function(){
    // only things to be loaded on dom ready
    // e.g.

    $('button#load_manual_trigger').bind('click', manual_func);
}

$(document).ready(on_ready_func);
```

Happy Coding.